# Why it is null when I'm calling a get method of one class from another class using reference i.e it prints out null

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I want to execute the `getName()` method on a `Visit`, which contains the return method of name but it is printing out "null"

```
public void getAllVisits() {
    Visit v = new Visit();

    for (int i = 0; i < myVisits.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println(v.getName());
        System.out.println(v.getAmount());
        System.out.println(v.getDate());
    }
}
```

This is the code in the Visit class

```
public Visit(){}

public Visit(double visitAmount, String Name)
{
    amount = visitAmount;
    doctorName = Name;        
}
 public String getName()
{
    return doctorName;
}
```

Comment: What makes you so sure that `v.getName()` is not returning `null`?  Show us the `Visit` class.

Comment: In that case `getName()` is returning either `null` or possibly `"null"`

Comment: It is printing out null to the terminal

Comment: You aren't instantiating v's member variables. So no matter how big myVisits is, v.method() will always be null. Unless your constructor sets values

Comment: Yes, I'm setting the values in the constructor @JamesSutherland

Comment: @pavan In which case can you edit your question to provide the constructor and show us where it's initialised. Can you also clarify whether it's printing out null, or you're getting a `NullPointerException`, as you've tagged this question. If you're not getting an exception, I'd remove the tag...

Comment: please edit your question rather than post code in a comment. Please post the entire class.

Comment: @pavan Not in the code you posted you're not.  You're calling the empty constructor instead.

Comment: How to make it correct so that i can get what i want?? @Powerlord

Answer (score 1):

You're not initializing your Visit object properly, you should be calling:

```
Visit v = new Visit(100, "Visit Name");
```

Also, as someone pointed out, the loop doesn't do anything since it always calls the same instance of v. What you probably want is something like:

```
List<Visit> myVisits;

public void someOtherMethod() {
    myVisits = new ArrayList<Visit>();

    Visit visit1 = new Visit(100, "Visit Name");
    myVisits.add(visit1);
}

public void getAllVisits() {
    for (Visit visit : myVisits) {
        System.out.println(visit.getName());
        System.out.println(visit.getAmount());
        System.out.println(visit.getDate());
    }
}
```

Comment: But it will be restricted to only those values but instead i just need to print all the values in the array!!

Comment: you didn't post what myVisits contains? Is this an array of Visit objects? If so, why are you doing new Visit()?

Comment: So what should I do in order to print the returned values from those methods in the Visit class?

Comment: A patient has many visits, so ArrayList<Visit> myVisits is an array, so to get all the visits i want the name and the amount to be printed out